# Fizzbuzz Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, fizzbuzz

I need some help. My fizz-buzz code is correct but when my page loads it is not showing. 
Can someone help what I am missing?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>FizzBuzz Challenge</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>FizzBuzz Challenge</h1>
<p>View FizzBuzz Output</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FizzBuzz.js"></script

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function FizzBuzz() {
    var display = numCount;

    if (numCount % 3 == 0) {
        display = ("Fizz");
    } else if (numCount % 5 == 0) {
        display = ("Buzz");
    } else if (numCount % 3 == 0 && numCount % 5 == 0) {
        display = ("FizzBuzz");

    } else {

        console.log(display);
    }
}

for (numCount = 1; numCount < 100; numCount++) {
    FizzBuzz(numCount);
}
```

Comment: Open your browser's web tools and go to Console. There you will see the messages of your code. In JavaScript, calling `console.log(...)` does not print anything in the web page, only in the console.

Comment: Your last `else if` is unreachable, if it would be true one of the preceding conditions would have also been true. Also, are you sure that you want the log to happen in the `else` condition instead of always?

Comment: I just saw, you've also not closed your script tag, it's missing a `>`

Comment: @PaulS. Surprisingly, it still works without the closing `>` . Tried with both Chrome and Firefox. But it's better to provide correct html anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this JavaScript code :

```
(function executeThis() {

    function FizzBuzz(numCount) {
        if (numCount % 15 == 0) {
            document.write("FizzBuzz ");
        } else if (numCount % 3 == 0) {
            document.write("Fizz ");
        } else if (numCount % 5 == 0) {
            document.write("Buzz ");
        } else {
            document.write(numCount + ' ');
        }
    }

    for (var numCount = 1; numCount < 100; numCount++) {
        FizzBuzz(numCount);
    }
}());
```

Note that :

1. If a number is divisible with both 3 and 5 it is divisible with 15
2. [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) displays things in the page. You may also want to have a look at Angular or jQuery or another such library/framework.
3. add a space or other delimiter after each string you print
4. try to keep your variables like `numCount` local in each function instead of making them global

Comment: Please note `document.write` will call `document.open` if the page has reached _DOMContentLoaded_, which will cause the document to be emptied.

Comment: Thanks Manos, this works and shorter code too!  what does the "+" sign do in this line?  else {
            document.write(numCount + ' ');

Comment: @Paul Correct. And the output would look ugly anyway. My first recommendation for displaying would be Angular, jquery or another such framework/library

Comment: This `numCount + ' '` converts `numCount` to a string and appends a space. Such type conversions are very concise in JavaScript but can also lead to nasty surprises.

Comment: thanks. Also why did you put this at the end of the code "( ) )" instead of  this " } ;  "  ?

Comment: To make the executeThis function "self executing". executeThis serves to create a scope and avoid global variables. executeThis could be anonymous.